# Formatting number to specific format in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I want to convert integer number (milliseconds) to the following format:

```
HH:MM:SS,SSS
```

For example time stamp 12,5 seconds is `00:00:12,500` and 1 hour, 38 minutes and 10 seconds like that `01:38:10,000`.

I am pretty new to Lisp programming but here is what I have so far.

```
(defun ms->time (ms)
  (let ((hours 0)
        (minutes 0)
        (seconds ms))
    (progn
      (and (>= seconds 3600000)
           (progn
             (setq hours (floor (/ seconds 3600000)))
             (setq seconds (mod seconds 3600000))))
      (and (>= seconds 60000)
           (progn
             (setq minutes (floor (/ seconds 60000)))
             (setq seconds (mod seconds 60000))))
    (format nil "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~6,'0:d" hours minutes seconds))))
```

And here is the simple output:

```
CL> (ms->time 12500)
"00:00:12,500"
CL> (ms->time 5890000)
"01:38:10,000"
```

Looks great, exactly as I wanted. However...

```
CL> (ms->time 0)
"00:00:000000"    
CL> (ms->time 999)
"00:00:000999"
```

How can I fix this problem? `format` is so advanced that I am pretty sure there is a way to do what I need. And of course if you have any ideas how to change my function to be more *lispy* please - do not hesitate. My current approach looks almost the same as my C++ version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy solution would be to separate seconds into their own component like hours and minutes. I also use `LET*` to shadow `MS` in order to avoid having to `SETQ` variables:

```
(defun ms->time (ms)
  (let* ((hours (floor ms 3600000))
         (ms (mod ms 3600000))
         (minutes (floor ms 60000))
         (ms (mod ms 60000))
         (seconds (floor ms 1000))
         (ms (mod ms 1000)))
    (format nil "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d,~3,'0d"
            hours minutes seconds ms)))

(ms->time 0)
;=> "00:00:00,000"
(ms->time 999)
;=> "00:00:00,999"
```

I left out the checks for whether there are enough milliseconds to make hours or minutes. The math works out anyway, and I can't imagine the extra computation being a bottleneck.

Comment: Note that `(floor (/ x a))` can be written as `(floor x a)`.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Oh, I never noticed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**About style (see jkiiski's answer for the functional improvement):**

- no `PROGN` needed inside `LET`
- using `AND` this way is unusual, avoid
- `(floor (/ x a))` is `(floor x a)`

Your code can be written a bit shorter.

- top function variables can be specified in the arglist as `&aux`. This can be useful to remove one layer of parentheses, by getting rid of the `LET`.
- `WHEN` instead of `AND`
- `SETF` instead of `SETQ` - it can set more than one place

**Example**:

```
(defun ms->time (ms &aux (hours 0) (minutes 0) (seconds ms))
  (when (>= seconds 3600000)
    (setf hours   (floor seconds 3600000)
          seconds (mod seconds 3600000)))
  (when (>= seconds 60000)
    (setf minutes (floor seconds 60000)
          seconds (mod seconds 60000)))
  (format nil "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~6,'0:d" hours minutes seconds))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do this by using the fact that `floor` returns two values (the integer part of the division, as well as the reminder).

```
(defun ms->time (ms &optional (stream nil))
  (multiple-value-bind (rest ms) (floor ms 1000)
    (multiple-value-bind (rest s) (floor rest 60)
      (multiple-value-bind (h m) (floor rest 60)
        (format stream "~2,'0d:~2,'0d:~2,'0d,~3,'0d" h m s ms)))))
```